# adding legend to a bar plot (R ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, geom-col

I am trying to add a legend to my bar plot, with no success.
This is what my data looks like: three columns, first is a factor with a group name, and than two numeric called "1st_dose" and "2nd_dose" (those are rates of vaccinations among that age group).

my data:

```
structure(list(`age group` = structure(1:9, .Label = c("10-19", 
"20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-89", 
"90+"), class = "factor"), `1st_dose` = c(20.9, 72.8, 77.4, 82.2, 
87.1, 88.6, 97.2, 94.5, 97.3), `2nd_dose` = c(17.7, 62.8, 69.1, 
75.4, 80.9, 84, 93.6, 90.6, 91.6)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

first graph I made was with this code:

```
ggplot(data)+geom_bar(aes(x=`age group`, y = `1st_dose`), stat = "identity")+
  geom_bar(aes(x=`age group`, y = `2nd_dose`), stat = "identity", fill="skyblue", alpha = 0.5)+
  ylab("percent")+ggtitle("Vaccination rate by age group \n Israel") +
  theme_bw()+theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This came out exactly as I wanted, [but how do I add a legend to this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZqwG.png)

then I tried to turn my data long:

```
data_long <- data %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(`1st_dose`,`2nd_dose`), names_to = "dose",
                                   values_to = "rate")
```

and tried two variations of graphs which have legends, but don't look the way I want them too:

```
ggplot(data_long,aes(x = `age group`, y = `rate`, fill = `dose`)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[I don't want it separate like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJLzJ.png)

```
ggplot(data_long,aes(x = `age group`, y = `rate`, fill = `dose`)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = T))
```

[but this comes out stacked, and I don't want it to be over 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUiVW.png)

any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include your data as an object: use `dput(data)` this will help others test and verify solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I just did. I wasn't familiar with dput, that is a useful tool

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- 
  data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-`age group`)
  

ggplot(data1)+
  geom_col(aes(x=`age group`, y = value, fill = name), position = position_dodge(width = 0, preserve = "total"), width = 1.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray10", "skyblue"))+
  labs(x = "Age",
       y = "Percent",
       fill = "Dose")+
  ggtitle("Vaccination rate by age group \n Israel") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I'll learn more about `position = position_dodge(width = 0, preserve = "total")`, looks like that is where the solution is